# Calculating cumulative sum over non unique list elements in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a PySpark dataframe with a column containing lists. The list items might overlap across rows. I need the cumulative sum of unique list elements down through the rows ordered by 'orderCol' column. In my application there might be millions of rows and hundreds of items in each list. I can't seem to wrap my brain around how to do this in PySpark so that it scales and would be grateful for any ideas big or small on how to solve it.

I have posted input and desired output to give an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("myApp") \
    .getOrCreate()

data = [{"node": 'r1', "items": ['a','b','c','d'], "orderCol": 1},
        {"node": 'r2', "items": ['e','f','g','a'], "orderCol": 2},
        {"node": 'r3', "items": ['h','i','g','b'], "orderCol": 3},
        {"node": 'r4', "items": ['j','i','f','c'], "orderCol": 4},
        ]

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()

data_out = [{"node": 'r1', "items": ['a','b','c','d'], "orderCol": 1, "cumulative_item_count": 4},
        {"node": 'r2', "items": ['e','f','g','a'], "orderCol": 2, "cumulative_item_count": 7},
        {"node": 'r3', "items": ['h','i','g','b'], "orderCol": 3, "cumulative_item_count": 9},
        {"node": 'r4', "items": ['j','i','f','c'], "orderCol": 4, "cumulative_item_count": 10},
        ]

df_out = spark.createDataFrame(data_out)
df_out.show()
```

Comment: are you partitioning by any field? if you don't have a partition, then a window operation will degrade the performance for large datasets to the point where it may no longer be performant

Comment: In the solution suggested by @notNull the partitioning is on lit(1) so basically single node partitioning, as far as I understand it. I don't quite understand how to make a cumulative sum if you include some partitioning since all previous rows are needed to calculate the next.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately given your use case, i don't think pyspark is going to offer much of an advantage in performance because it's assumed that your data can be partitioned in some way. using `F.lit(1)` gets around the pyspark warning message regarding single partitions, but won't offer an actual improvement in performance. if i have some time later, i might run some basic benchmarks comparing pyspark to pandas for the cumulative sum operation to see which is faster

Answer (score 2):

Try with **window function** using **`unboundedPreceeding`** to **`currentRow`**.

Then `flatten` the nested array.

Finally we will `array_distinct`+ `size` functions to count distinct elements in the array.

**`Example:`**

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
data = [{"node": 'r1', "items": ['a','b','c','d'], "orderCol": 1},
        {"node": 'r2', "items": ['e','f','g','a'], "orderCol": 2},
        {"node": 'r3', "items": ['h','i','g','b'], "orderCol": 3},
        {"node": 'r4', "items": ['j','i','f','c'], "orderCol": 4},
        ]

w=Window.partitionBy(lit(1)).orderBy("orderCol").rowsBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, Window.currentRow)
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).\
  withColumn("temp_col",collect_list(col("items")).over(w)).\
  withColumn("cumulative_item_count",size(array_distinct(flatten(col("temp_col")))))
df.show(20,False)

#+------------+----+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
#|items       |node|orderCol|temp_col                                                |cumulative_item_count|
#+------------+----+--------+--------------------------------------------------------+---------------------+
#|[a, b, c, d]|r1  |1       |[[a, b, c, d]]                                          |4                    |
#|[e, f, g, a]|r2  |2       |[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, a]]                            |7                    |
#|[h, i, g, b]|r3  |3       |[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, a], [h, i, g, b]]              |9                    |
#|[j, i, f, c]|r4  |4       |[[a, b, c, d], [e, f, g, a], [h, i, g, b], [j, i, f, c]]|10                   |
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your suggestion does indeed work on my test data but I am a little worried about the consequences of partitioning to a single dataframe. Won't this break pyspark's ability to parallelise the computation and rely solely on a huge machine? If this is indeed the case it wont work as the data sizes I expect are huge.